# Display snippets of Page data in left sidebar / main body / right sidebar of WP template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have each Page content broken down into categories of content, eg: Overview, Product detail and courses / material. All in one page/post in WP.

I want to display Overview data in the main body, product detail in the left sidebar and courses / material in the right sidebar.

How would I go about doing that, I have scoured the web but can't find anything concrete.

Any suggestions would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were in your situation, I'd think about storing your 'sections' in custom fields. I might be able to help, but can you provide a link to what you have so far?

**EDIT**

I think custom meta fields would be the best option, so I created a lightweight plugin that'll add metaboxes to your pages, storing data for an overview, product details, and courses/materials.

Here's a link to the plugin on [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?0061jwgg9q3hhw3)

*Changelog*

- 1.0 Original Release
- 1.1 Added Widgets
- 1.2 Fixed function calls

To call the details in your theme, you can use the following functions:

- `<?php get_content_overview($id) ?>`  or

  `<?php echo (get_post_meta($id, 'get_content_overview', TRUE)) ?>`

  // Fetches details from 'Overview' meta box
- `<?php get_content_details($id) ?>`  or

  `<?php echo (get_post_meta($id, 'get_content_details', TRUE)) ?>`

  // Fetches details from 'Details' meta box
- `<?php get_content_supplements($id) ?>` or

  `<?php echo (get_post_meta($id, 'get_content_supplements', TRUE)) ?>`

  // Fetches details from 'Courses/Materials' meta box

Insert the widgets in your sidebar, they'll only display if the page being viewed has the specified meta content.

Here's the raw code (from v1.0):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Content Meta Boxes (MB)
Plugin URI: http://mechabyte.com
Description: Displays custom content meta boxes.
Author: Matthew Smith
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://mechabyte.com
*/

function get_content_overview() {
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'get_content_overview', TRUE)) {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'get_content_overview', TRUE);
    }
}

function get_content_details() {
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'get_content_details', TRUE)) {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'get_content_details', TRUE);
    }
}

function get_content_supplements() {
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'get_content_supplements', TRUE)) {
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'get_content_supplements', TRUE);
    }
}


// Add the Meta Box
function add_content_boxes() {
add_meta_box(
    'custom_meta_box', // $id
    'Custom Content Boxes', // $title
    'show_content_metabox', // $callback
    'page', // $page
    'normal', // $context
    'high'); // $priority
}
 add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_content_boxes');

// Field Array
$prefix = 'get_content';
$content_meta_fields = array(
array(
    'label'=> 'Product Overview',
    'desc'  => 'Overview Data',
    'id'    => $prefix.'_overview',
    'type'  => 'textarea'
),
array(
    'label'=> 'Product Details',
    'desc'  => 'Add some details about the product',
    'id'    => $prefix.'_details',
    'type'  => 'textarea'
),
array(
    'label'=> 'Courses/Materials',
    'desc'  => 'Don\'t forget to add your courses and materials!',
    'id'    => $prefix.'_supplements',
    'type'  => 'textarea'
)
 );

// The Callback
function show_content_metabox() {
global $content_meta_fields, $post;
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_meta_box_nonce"     value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

    // Begin the field table and loop
echo '<table class="form-table">';
foreach ($content_meta_fields as $field) {
    // get value of this field if it exists for this post
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
    // begin a table row with
    echo '<tr>
            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
            <td>';
            switch($field['type']) {
                // text
                    case 'text':
                        echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" />
                            <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
                // checkbox
                    case 'checkbox':
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/>
                            <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';
                    break;
                // textarea
                    case 'textarea':
                        echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea>
                            <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';
                    break;
            } //end switch
    echo '</td></tr>';
} // end foreach
echo '</table>'; // end table
 }

 // Save the Data
 function save_content_meta($post_id) {
global $content_meta_fields;

// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
    return $post_id;
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
    return $post_id;
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
        return $post_id;
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
}

// loop through fields and save the data
foreach ($content_meta_fields as $field) {
    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
    if ($new && $new != $old) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
    } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
} // end foreach
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_content_meta');  

?>
```

Comment: I don't have this published at the moment its still in dev, I was looking at Custom fields, but it seems as if you can only save limited data in there. I probably require about 1000 + characters per 'Section".

Comment: Another thought I had was to add some div ID's and try and pull that data through to sidebar somehow.

Comment: I'm not trying to downplay your ideas, but I think custom fields would be a simpler option, and after digging around for a while, I can't find any mention of them allowing less characters than a post itself :P

Comment: That way, you'd also be able to add custom meta boxes to make repeating the process easier for multiple posts

Comment: "add custom meta boxes to make repeating the process easier for multiple posts" - can you elaborate

Comment: Custom meta boxes allow you to easily add custom field data to posts without remembering the field id's. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Wow Matt, you're the man!! Tx so much for your feedback! I searched "Custom meta boxes" and looks like its the way to go. As the site will be maintained by non developers this should be the easiest option for general content maintenance once setup.

Comment: Will give your code a whirl and let you know how I do. Tx again.

Comment: Hey Grant, I was bored and wanted to make your day great, so I updated the file with some widgets. You can add them to your sidebar and they'll only display if the page being viewed has the related custom field data. I tested them quickly, but give 'em a whirl and see if they're ok.

Comment: I added the following to my page.php: <?php get_content_overview(); ?>
<?php get_content_details(); ?>
<?php get_content_supplements(); ?> + installed the plugin and activate it. I then added some text to the pages in the Custom Meta Boxes, but nothing shows up.

Comment: That is very strange.. For me, the widgets are working to display the content, but not the page itself. Can you accomplish what you were trying to do with the widgets? If not, I'll start trying to find the root of this problem.

Comment: @Grant- I don't know why the functions aren't working, but you can just insert the following in your theme:

`<?php echo (get_post_meta($id, 'get_content_overview', TRUE))  ?>`

`<?php echo (get_post_meta($id, 'get_content_details', TRUE))  ?>`

`<?php echo (get_post_meta($id, 'get_content_supplements', TRUE))  ?>`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, had no idea one could do this in WP. I am not getting any erros and I placed comments either side of the <!--<?php get_content_overview(); ?> -> to see what if I am editing the right page and its correct. But nothing shows. Using the latest version of WP 3.3.1. Linux ubuntu 11.10, apache 2 et al.

Comment: I pasted the additional code into the theme and one of the custom fields has shown up. Looks like I should be able to debug. Tx so much for your help you have really "made my day". Its been a long one I am going to pick this up again in the am. It's midnight here.

Comment: Whoops! Gave you the wrong code again, since I can't edit my comment, I just updated my answer

Comment: Great! Btdubs, I fixed the functions, just make sure you grab the most recent download from my answer and use the functions shown.

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly now. Thanks again it's the solution I was looking for.